# A function that is surjective but not injective, and function that is injective but not surjective

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

$(b)$ $f$ is surjective

$(c)$ $|A| = |B|$

Right now I'm having trouble coming up with examples that would not contradict what I proved. If the function is going from A to A, then the cardinality of the domain and codomain are the same, and if it is either surjective or injective, then wouldn't it have to also be injective or surjective, respectively?

Comment: Is the set $ A $ finite or not ?

Comment: The previous exercise only mentions a specific type of set, so an example you're looking for necessarily has to not be that type of set. This is why there is no contradiction and it also tells you where to look for such an example.

Comment: Why don't you use MathJax?

Comment: Why  in the name of Barney the tap dancing goat, did you edit this question to leave out *ALL* essential details?  "Right now I'm having trouble coming up with examples that would not contradict what I proved."  How the heck are we supposed to know what you have just proven?????

Comment: " If the function is going from A to A, then the cardinality of the domain and codomain are the same"  That's only true if $f$ is *BOTH* surjective *AND* injective.  If $f$ is one or the other or neither than it is not true.   If $A$ and $B$ are finite then injective and surjective must both be true or false but if $A$ and $B$ are infinite they do not.  ... Remember the "paradox" that there are as many odd integers as there are any integers.

Comment: I did not edit my question

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = x^3-3x$ is surjective but not injective

$g(x) = e^x$ is injective but not surjective.

And both are functions from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

Comment: Thank you! How could I say that these do not contradict the previous exercise I answered?

Comment: The function $f$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @gibbs, I can fix that, thanks.

Comment: Of course you can, I was just pointing out a triviality.

Comment: @darrenz123 All continuous subsets of the real numbers are uncountable, so they are the same cardinality.  I suspect the previous exercise was limited to functions on countable sets.

Answer (score 1):

This result can be extended to infinite set like $\mathbb{R}$ in a certain way: it's the *Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem*.
If there exists an injection from $A$ to $B$ and an injection from $B$ to $A$ then it exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\arctan x$ is injective but not surjective, whereas $g\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=x^3-x$ is surjective but not injective. These examples do not contradict your exercise because domain and codomain contain infinitely many elements.

Answer (score 0):

The key word is "finite".  If $A$ is finite then that *would* be a contradiction.  So to find any example $A$ must be infinite.

I suggest you let $A = \mathbb Z$.

A function that is *not* surjective means that $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ means $f$ maps to *some* of $\mathbb Z$ but not all.  Can you think of any examples?  What about a function that maps to only the *even* integers?  Or the odd integers?  Or every integer except the number $7$.

(Of course your example has to be injective which means no two values map to the same value)

Hmm... for the surjective and not injective maybe my suggestion that $A= \mathbb Z$ wasn't a very good one after all.

What about $A =\mathbb R$ and if $f$ is not injective then there are at least two input values that map to the same output value.  Can you think of any example where $f(x) = f(w)$ but $x \ne w$?

(Of course your example has to be surjective so every value is mapped and some are mapped to more than once... but if $f$ is continuous and $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(x) \to -\infty$ when $x\to -\infty$ that will happen automatically.  Can you think of any function that tends to $\pm \infty$ at the extremes but has values that have more than one input.)

(Hint:  Do you remember what the veritical line test is?  If $x \ne w$ but $f(x) = f(w)=k$ then $(x,f(x)=k)$ and $(w, f(w) = k)$ are to points on a vertical line.)